# Locating WordPress plugin source code used by this code

Tags: php, filter, wordpress, hook

I am trying to write a hook for [s2Member](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/s2member/):

I have trouble with the following code:

```
eval ('foreach(array_keys(get_defined_vars())as$__v)$__refs[$__v]=&$$__v;');
do_action ("ws_plugin__s2member_after_paypal_notify", get_defined_vars ());
unset ($__refs, $__v); /* Unset defined __refs, __v. */
```

1. What does `eval ('foreach(array_keys(get_defined_vars())as$__v)$__refs[$__v]=&$$__v;');` do, especially `&$$__v`?
2. I can’t find the source code for `ws_plugin__s2member_after_paypal_notify`. Is this supposed to be a class? How can I find the source code for this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. eval takes a string and then runs it as if it was PHP code. In this particular case, the code takes a string and manipulates it trying to insert some variable names or variable addresses. Eval is a very very bad practice and an antipattern. If you can - don't use this plugin, as it is probably full of security holes.
2. `ws_plugin__s2member_after_paypal_notify` is a hook. WordPress hooks are wonderful - it's like an event in JavaScript. For example, if you click on something in the page, JavaScript fires the onclick event and anyone can attach to that event and run some code. WordPress hooks work the same way. Now when you run `do_action ("ws_plugin__s2member_after_paypal_notify", get_defined_vars ());` any third-party plugins that you have installed can attach to it and perform an action.

If you want to find bits of code that run on this action, look for `add_action('ws_plugin__s2member_after_paypal_notify' ...)` (this is how you attach to the hook), or simply for `ws_plugin__s2member_after_paypal_notify` in your *wp-content* directory (any plugin and/or theme can attach to this hook).

Comment: @valentinas Thanks a lot! Do you mean `ws_plugin__s2member_after_paypal_notify` is not a funtion or class, so there is no source code for it. It is like a bookmark or landmark, saved for later use. Am I right? I find something from the author: http://www.s2member.com/forums/topic/payment-notification-hook/

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's like saying "hey, if anyone wants do do anything with 'ws_plugin__s2member_after_paypal_notify' - do it now"

Comment: @valentinas Even the `eval` line is dangerous, I still want to know what `&$$__v` means. I have never seen the `$$`,  and does `&` means 'getting address'?

Comment: $$ denotes a variable variable.  They're not used often as they tend to be confusing (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).  & denotes a reference, which isn't technically an address in PHP.